# Help center page contains unparsed markdown (MSE only)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, meta, help-center

On the [how to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page on MSE we see the following:

> `...are not about the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) as defined in the help center.`

The markdown did not parse. Please edit to parse the markdown.

[image]

Comment: Ah, interesting. The part between "not about" and "as defined" is a `$Topic` variable that gets auto-inserted based on the site, and apparently doesn't get run through the parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, someone put markdown in a setting that isn't parsed for markdown.

I removed the markdown bits.

Comment: But why not make it a link as that someone intended to do?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - order of execution. And in order to fix the broken as soon as possible, before looking at a better long term solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Links are possible there since "defined in the help center" is a link. So why not make "network" link as well, manually, until the markup parser is fixed/attached in there?

Comment: @Sha - isn't that simple. given, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253286/help-center-page-contains-unparsed-markdown-mse-only/253298?noredirect=1#comment827344_253286

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the comment. Guess we now know who that someone is, too? ;)

Comment: Anyway, isn't it better to mark this completed when the `$Topic` variable will support markdown?

Comment: It is used in a bunch of places, so not sure it _should_ at all. Doesn't make sense in certain contexts.